# Python beautiful soup ignore class

Tags: python

Im grabbing some links from a website using beautiful soup.

they are all in a div class called col-sm-4
however under this class is also another div with and id called fyfy and i need to ignore all the links under this div

right now my script looks like this but it also gets the div id=fyfy links that i need to get rid of.

`divtag = soup.find("div","col-sm-4 well")`
 `links = divtag.findAll("a")`

EDIT:
html from website below. i need to grab the javascript links only and ignore the others.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 well">

<div id="fyfy" style="display:none;">
<strong><p>Manglende plugin?</p></strong>
<a href="http://someserver.com/misc/plugin/YouSee.msi" class="btn btn-primary">Windows</a><br>
<a href="http://blapd.org/trw/yousee.pkg" class="btn btn-primary">OSX</a> <br>
<a href="https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5491044" class="btn btn-primary">OSX Fix (hvis ingen lyd/billede)</a><br>
<br>
<br>
<strong><p>TV-GLAD på andre enheder</p></strong>
<a href="http://blapd.org/trw/apple.html" class="btn btn-primary">På OSX med Safari?</a> <br>
<a href="http://blapd.org/trw/m" class="btn btn-primary">Mobilside</a><br>
<a href="http://blapd.be/file/sxV18.zip" class="btn btn-primary">XBMC plugin</a><br>
<br>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-warning" onClick="showHideFyfy();" id="fyfyknap">Vis Info</a>

<br>
<br>
<strong>DR Kanaler<br></strong>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr01-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr01_0@147054/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 20);">DR1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr02-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr02_0@147055/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 21);">DR2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr03-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr03_0@147056/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 701);">DR3</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr06-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr06_0@147059/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 31);">DR Ultra</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr04-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr04_0@147057/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 38);">DR K</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr05-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr05_0@147058/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 50);">DR Ramasjang</a><br>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: you can probably use a css selector but I'd need to see the page source or some example html to tell you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it to work by cutting out the .col-sm-4 and search for javascript:changeChannel. like this:

```
divtag = soup.select('a[href^="javascript:changeChannel"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming back around to answer since nobody did yesterday:

You can use a css selector directly on `soup`:

```
soup.select('.col-sm-4 > a[href]')
Out[20]: 
[<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr01-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr01_0@147054/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 20);">DR1</a>,
 <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr02-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr02_0@147055/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 21);">DR2</a>,
 <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr03-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr03_0@147056/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 701);">DR3</a>,
 <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr06-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr06_0@147059/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 31);">DR Ultra</a>,
 <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr04-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr04_0@147057/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 38);">DR K</a>,
 <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr05-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr05_0@147058/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 50);">DR Ramasjang</a>]
```

This says: select the *direct* descendants of the `col-sm-4` class which are an `a` tag with an `href` attribute.  You can read more about `select` [in the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). I added in that href filter because I figured you didn't want this tag:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" onClick="showHideFyfy();" id="fyfyknap">Vis Info</a>
```

If you did, just remove the `[href]` filter.

Comment: Tried this but i only get [] as output

Comment: Okay I got it to work by cutting out the .col-sm-4 and search for javascript:changeChannel. like this:


divtag = soup.select('a[href^="javascript:changeChannel"]')



however now i can't clean clean the output up using .split
I need to get the http:// part of the links in a list